# How can I edit my citation in the text in apalike2 style?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am using winedt and I am trying to make my bibliography. I am completely satisfied with the way my reference is written, though my citation in the text is troubling. The name of  the author doesn't go into the parenthesis while the year does! the output is something like this:
Some text Pascual-Hortal & Saura (2006).
I need the author part in the parenthesis.

Here are the codes I used:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myhyperref}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{#2 \ref*{#1}}}

\usepackage{natbib}

Some text \cite{pascual06}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{testfour}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `texdoc natbib`, page 7.

Answer (score 1):

> The name of the author doesn't go into the parenthesis while the year does

To generate a parenthesis-style citation call-out, you must change

```
\cite{pascual06}
```

to

```
\citep{pascual06}
```